# Comparing elements of one array with an arraylist of array for equality in drools

Tags: arrays, arraylist, drools

I have a array containing 3 string elements. I want to compare this array elements with another arrayList which contains many arrays of 3 string elements and check which array matches.

```
actualArray = {"query1","date1","result1"};

arrayListToCompare = {{"query1","date1","result1"}, {"query2","date2","result2"},       {"query3","date3","result3"}}
```

I want to comapre the individual elements of "actualAarray" with elements of "arrayListToCompare" to check whether they are equal. Please help me in writing a rule in drools.

Comment: Maybe worth removing the "java" tag from the question. Everyone is providing answers for how to do it in Java. :)

Answer (score 3):

These are the two lists and how they are inserted into Working Memory:

```
 List<String> los1 = Arrays.asList( "One", "Two", "Three" );
 List<String> los2 = Arrays.asList( "Huey", "Dewey", "Louie" );
 List<String> los3 = Arrays.asList( "Tick", "Trick", "Track" );
 List<List<String>> lol = Arrays.asList( los1, los2, los3 );
 kSession.insert( lol );
 List<String> los = Arrays.asList( "Huey", "Dewey", "Louie" );
 kSession.insert( los );
 kSession.fireAllRules();
```

This is the rule:

```
rule findinlist
when
    $l1: List()
    $l2: List( this contains $l1 )
then
    System.out.println( $l2 + " contains " + $l1 );
end
```

This is the output:

```
[[One, Two, Three], [Huey, Dewey, Louie], [Tick, Trick, Track]] contains [Huey, Dewey, Louie]
```

Normally you wouldn't insert "naked" List objects like this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for your String example.

Java code to insert facts / execute rules:

```
List<String> arrayToCompare1 = Arrays.asList("query1", "date1", "result1");
List<String> arrayToCompare2 = Arrays.asList("query2", "date2", "result2");
List<String> arrayToCompare3 = Arrays.asList("query3", "date3", "result3");

List<List<String>> arraysToCompare = Arrays.asList(
        arrayToCompare1, arrayToCompare2, arrayToCompare3);

ksession.setGlobal("arraysToCompare", arraysToCompare);

List<String> actualArray = Arrays.asList("query1", "date1", "result1");

List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
facts.add(actualArray);

ksession.execute(facts);
```

DRL code to do the match:

```
global java.util.List arraysToCompare;

rule "Match rule"
when
    $list : List()
    $listToCompare : List(this == $list) from arraysToCompare
then
    System.out.println("List: " + $list);
    System.out.println("List: " + $listToCompare);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
  String[] actualArray = {"query1", "date1", "result1"};

    String[][] arrayListToCompare = {{"query1", "date1", "result1"},
    {"query2", "date2", "result2"}};
    boolean found=false;

    for (String[] element : arrayListToCompare) {

        if(Arrays.deepToString(actualArray)
                .equals(Arrays.deepToString(element))){
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }

   if(found){
         System.out.println("Matched ");
   }
   else{
            System.out.println("Not Matched ");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate your `List` in `for` loop get first value of list using `get` method which is again `list` so iterate that `list` and compare with your `array` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String s : actualArray){
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListToCompare.length; i++){{
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayListToCompare[i].length; i++)
            if (s.equals(arrayListToCompare[i][j])){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```